# Custom irb not printing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

Trying to write a custom irb for a gem to ease debugging. At the point where the shell loads and you can use it like `ruby console` but running into this wall

```
MyClass.get_last_instance
=>  
_.attributes
=> {'attribute'=> 'test'}
```

The instance was found but a blank string is echo'ed. Here are the requires involved in starting the shell

```
 require 'irb'
 require 'irb/completion'
 require 'debugger'
```

I tried reading through the rails source code, didn't get very far, mostly because I didn't really know what I was looking for. I think I'm just missing a require of a part of rails that echos objects.

Answer (score 0):

create a `.irbrc` in your home path for ubuntu/osx and use the below code, it will work. Also you can add additional gems also `debugger` or `irb`

```
# print SQL to STDOUT
if ENV.include?('RAILS_ENV') && !Object.const_defined?('RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER')
  require 'logger'
end

# Autocomplete
require 'irb/completion'

# Prompt behavior
ARGV.concat [ "--readline", "--prompt-mode", "simple" ]

# History
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"

# Easily print methods local to an object's class
class Object
  def local_methods
    (methods - Object.instance_methods).sort
  end
end

# copy a string to the clipboard
def pbcopy(string)
  `echo "#{string}" | pbcopy`
  string
end
require "rubygems"
```